# Android, How to properly scan and filter ble UUID's

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with BluetoothLe on Android (min API : 21+). Currently the procedure of filtering service uuid's works, but not quite as expected. Below is a code segment used for setting up the basic scanner parameters, this is what currently works. Based on areas of other work with Ble, (iOS, Embedded Hardware) it becomes apparent that there are abilities to filter Ble devices based on their 16-bit UUID assignments only. Which brings me to Android... I realized android has had a rather rough start to Ble and its rather segmented ecosystem of devices, but I fail to see how/why android cant follow similar paths with the UUID's like other platforms. As all the UUID's coming from the Bluetooth SIG are 16-bit identifiers only with a mere definition of a UUID_BASE (00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB).

```
...
// devices UUID service
ParcelUuid parcelUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("1F0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201"));
// devices UUID service mask
ParcelUuid parcelUuidMask = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("00000D0C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));

// Filters and Settings
scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(parcelUuid, parcelUuidMask).build();
scanFilterList.add(scanFilter);
scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).build();

// Scanning Started
mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilterList, scanSettings, scanCallback);
...
```

With all that stated above, I have two Embedded Hardware devices broadcasting Two of their own UUID Services that are very similar to one another but different non the less. Below are those UUID's, in all accounts only the MSB(Most Signifigant Byte) is the differentiator amongst them all. Also there Device Names are different.

```
Device One:
Service 1 - 1F0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201
Service 2 - 2F0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201

Device Two:
Service 1 - EF0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201
Service 2 - FF0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201

Common Identifier amongst the UUID's:
0x0D0C
```

From the code segment provided earlier, the ParcelUuid that is used in the setServiceUuid method appears to require an exact match for the scanner to even return a device, despite the matching mask needed. How then, do you make the request to the drivers/hardware to filter only by 16-bit Identifiers instead of the full 128-bit Identifiers?? Because the model I have presented above with the two different devices, each with their own Service UUID's different from the other, isn't capable of scanning and returning all the devices wanted or expected.

I feel like the problem I'm having is two-fold but needs to addressed, because I cant seem to find the answer anywhere. I have searched high and low for all forum post, stack questions/answer that touch on this topic but none of them appear to pop out as what I'm looking for. I'm not sure if my understanding of filtering on android is faulty, if android is missing features, or inability to find such features in the supplied classes of android. I have a few thoughts on how to accomplish this "feature" in software but it will be rather ugly, time consuming, and taxing on the battery. One such example is scanning openly and filtering it manually. But I think there is or should be a feature to support 128-bit AND 16-bit UUID filtering when scanning through devices.

Can anyone help shed light on this????

Also, apologies for the length of this posted question...

Comment: Any luck yet? I'm trying to figure this out as well, but didn't manage so far.

Answer (score 1):

The mask i should be opposite - use 1's for bits to include and 0's for those that should be ignored.

```
filter:  1F0E0D0C-0B0A-0909-0807-060504030201
mask:    0000FFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Result is that any device which has '0D0C' is included. You'd probably want a "tighter" filter with more similarities in it than this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to filter on, but if you simply want to apply the filter ????0D0C-????-????-????-????????????, you should have the parcelUuid set to 00000D0C-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and the parcelUuidMask set to 0000FFFF-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

Comment: I have tried this with no luck... the onScanResult never returns.

Comment: Exactly how do your advertisement data and scan response look like?

Comment: ScanResult{mDevice=F5:00:00:05:70:83, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[1f0e0d0c-0b0a-0909-0807-060504030201], mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=BLUE], mRssi=-38, mTimestampNanos=624459810326031}

Comment: not sure how to go about getting all advertisement data from device in android studio. the above is a copy paste from the debugger per the results given by the callback.

Comment: Well according to the documentation that should work... Have you tried another Android device?

Comment: yes, sort of.. I have a limited selection of devices, a Nexus 9 Tablet, Nexus 5x, Moto G4Plus. All the devices are running Android 7.1.1 or higher. All appear to exhibit the same results.

Comment: ran through all devices again with similar results, the suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: Do you possibly have a hci snoop log to share?

Comment: Not sure how to share it here.. But i have a snoop log of the device performing an open scan and another with the scan from the suggestions above.

Comment: Here are the two files, like i said before, they comprise of scans that are filtered and unfiltered. Also i am unable to decyfer their contents even after opening them up in wireshark.. not sure if these are produced correctly but here they are.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTtOlodjQYjMVplZ1U5VjBleXM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTtOlodjQYjSHNUa2UwM3RVMHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure if Wireshark implements Android's custom packets. You can find the format at https://source.android.com/devices/Android-6.0-Bluetooth-HCI-Reqs.pdf and manually decode it. Anyway, I see that filtering on Service UUID gets enabled, but I don't see any command that sets your specific UUID filter+mask (0x03 ­ APCF Service UUID). Could you restart Bluetooth and capture until you start scan, so that the Service UUID command gets included? If there are no such packets, I guess there must be some bug in Android's code... Have you tried Marshmallow or only Nougat?

Comment: As of today, i have only concerned myself with nougat because it happens to be on all the devices i have. I can try and locate a device with marshmallow, but I’m not holding my breathe. Anyways, is there any way to automate this hci snoop log -> a human readable format?? As the document you have linked will surely take time to dive into, ill be doing this in the mean time.

Comment: Also I’m not sure i fully understand this request, "Could you restart Bluetooth and capture until you start scan, so that the Service UUID command gets included?", as i have a button in the app that creates the filter and starts the scanning with a breakpoint set on the returning results of the scancallback. I start by enabling the snoop log and then launching the app via debugger, then waiting for my breakpoint(i have it on a 5 sec delay, so it will return but with nothing).

Comment: In the mean time, i have taken another log of the suggested code, hopefully it will be different as it is slightly larger than the last. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTtOlodjQYjM25oaFlwLXNxcDA/view?usp=sharing
But I’m not convinced running it again will produce different results in the log file unless there is something different you would like me to try other than the way i have been.

Comment: I’m not sure if sharing some source code will help reveal this problem, I’m doubtful (not that I’m against sharing or anything) that anything else is even relevant to this. But i have included a link a pic of the actually code segment relavant to the filtering, settings, and scanning of the bluetooth, this is wrapped in a onClick method for a button untill i can figure this out. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTtOlodjQYjQWNYazVla29YaUE/view?usp=sharing

Any help you can give me is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You should filter the BLE based on MAC addresses , they filter like a charm and perhaps if you have found the solution for the UUID filtering please do share.