# How to covert UUID to 16bit in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, android-bluetooth

I am working on bluetooth in my application. I found the article to display allocated UUID from the [doc](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf). The two id which I found for blood pressure monitor is `0x1810`, `0x2A35` which is for Blood Pressure and Blood Pressure Measurement respectively. I am totally new in this stuff so I don't understand properly. I found this [Stack overflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58643674/18958467) and [Stack overflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43687237/18958467). So I am adding value in my **btyeArrayof** but it giving me error on my side. Please also guide me how can I pass data to scan filters with multiple id

```
private fun scanFilters() {
        val scanFilterList = mutableListOf<ScanFilter>()
        val serviceUuidMaskString = "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF"
        val setServiceData = byteArrayOf(
            0x1810, 0x2A35
        )
        val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(setServiceData, serviceUuidMaskString).build()
        scanFilterList.add(scanFilter)
    }
```

Errors

```
The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte
```

on coming this piece of code

```
val setServiceData = byteArrayOf(0x1810, 0x2A35)
```

[image]

**Another error**

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ParcelUuid!
Found:
ByteArray
```

or

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ParcelUuid!
Found:
String

val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(setServiceData, serviceUuidMaskString).build()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express a 16-bit service UUID as a 128-bit service UUID like this:

`0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

So for Blood Pressure Management with 16-bit Service UUID 0x2A35 you can use:

`00002A35-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

And for Blood Pressure with 16-bit Service UUID 0x1810 you can use:

`00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

You can only put one service UUID in a single filter, so if you want to look for both, you need to use two filters.  Here's how you do that:

```
val filter1 = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(
  UUID.fromString("00002A35-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))).build();

val filter2 = ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(
  UUID.fromString("00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))).build();

scanFilterList.add(scanFilter1)
scanFilterList.add(scanFilter2)
```

Comment: can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027320/11560810) ?